# how to simplify the url

Tags: url, url-rewriting

Hi:
In my website I found that their url are very simple like:

http://example.com/questions/4486620/randomaccessfile-probelm

And generally the url should like:

http://example.com/questions?xx=4486620&title=randomaccessfile-probelm

That's to say there is no request parameters combined by "&" in the url.

How did they make it? Is there any framework?

**UPDATE:**
My application works under tomcat.

Comment: You would get better answers if you indicated what server you are running your website on as well as what application your website is running on.  The ways to handle this issue are different between an apache server running php or an IIS server running Asp.Net.

Comment: Thanks,I running my application under tomcat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On an apache web server you can do this using mod_rewrite http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Here is an example along with a tutorial...

The Apache rewrite engine is mainly used to turn dynamic url’s such as www.yoursite.com/product.php?id=123 into static and user friendly url’s such as www.yoursite.com/product/123

Read more about htaccess And mod_rewrite Tutorial by Blogstorm SEO Blog

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^product/([^/\.]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1 [L]
Another example, rewrite from:
www.yoursite.com/script.php?product=123 to www.yoursite.com/cat/product/123/

RewriteRule cat/(.*)/(.*)/$ /script.php?$1=$2
```

Read more here that example by the way is copied from http://www.blogstorm.co.uk/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/ - assigned kudos!

Comment: IIS has a similar solution, [ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) .  There is a free lite version of it.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know IIS's rewrite.

Comment: IIS URL Rewrite 2.0 is the offical plugin from microsoft and its free http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite