# Get the page file name from the address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if it would be possible to get the page name from the address bar using jquery or javascript. I know this can be done using PHP but don't really want to as it is only a html website.

I.e. if the address is `www.mywebsite.com/hello.htm` how do I get the `hello.htm` part out of the address.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: This is not the page TITLE, it is the filenmame. The TITLE is defined in the <title> tage in the HTML.

Comment: Yea that was a bit misleading for what I wanted, I've updated the question title

Comment: Do you want only the file name or the directory path plus the file name?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

```
alert(location.pathname)
```

If you don't want the leading slash, you can strip it out.

```
location.pathname.substring(1)
```

Comment: Awesome! didn't know javascript had a function like this.

Comment: @Jack To be accurate, it's not JavaScript, it's a host object added by the browser. For example, it doesn't exist in node.js

Answer (score 61):

Try this

`location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);`

`location.pathname` gives the part(domain not included) of the page url. To get only the filename you have to extaract it using `substring` method.

Comment: this is great - does exactly what I needed (fetch document name) - thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. But if URL ends with `/` then result will be null.

Comment: @Sariban D'Cl If there is no document name displayed in the URL then it returns NULL simply because there is no document being shown. Developers usually simplify URLs using [Mod_Rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529552/how-to-simplify-the-url?noredirect=1&lq=1) on Apache

Answer (score 5):

**Current page**: The single line sound more elegant to find the current page's file name:

```js
location.href.split("/").slice(-1)
```

or

```js
location.pathname.split("/").slice(-1)
```

This is cool to customize nav box's link, so the link toward the current is enlighten by a CSS class.

**JS:**

```
$('.menu a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('href') == location.href.split("/").slice(-1)){ $(this).addClass('curent_page'); }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
a.current_page { font-size: 2em; color: red; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var pageName = (function () {
        var a = window.location.href,
            b = a.lastIndexOf("/");
        return a.substr(b + 1);
    }());
```

Comment: What's up with the use of the self-invoking anonymous function? If you're going to wrap it up in a function, do so for repeated use.

Comment: Why?  Is the name of the page changing asynchronously?

Comment: The self invoking function lets you create temporary variables without affecting the global scope.

Answer (score 2):

The Location object is your friend:

```
var pageName = location.pathname.substring(1);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

Comment: I think the op was looking for the page file name and not the directory path.

Comment: @austincheney: I find that hard to believe... a file name includes the  path information. I rarely need just a name.

Answer (score 1):

`document.URL.match(/[^\/]+$/);`

Just a simple alternative.

**[document.URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/URL)** returns the document's location.
**[.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** is a method that filters a string using **[Regular Expression](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/JS/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions.html)**.
`/[^\/]+$/` fetches the rest of the string starting after the last occurring slash `/`.

**[demo](https://regex101.com/r/J2uvbG/2)**

Answer (score 0):

I've had an issue where i needed to remove the querystring parameters (?) and/or anchor (#) tags.  I did this:

```
var path = window.location.pathname.toLowerCase();
// find the end of path prior the Query and Anchor designations. strip off everything after the ? or #.  
//      if the ? is first, then use ?, else use the #, else use the string length.
// then replace all \ with /
// then split it into an array based on /
var pagePathAry = path.substr(0, path.indexOf("?") > -1 && path.indexOf("?") < path.indexOf("#") ? path.indexOf("?") : path.indexOf("#") > -1 ? path.indexOf("#") : path.length).replace("\\", "/").split("/");
// get the folder it's in
var subFolder = pagePathAry[pagePathAry.length - 2];
// get the page name
var pageName = pagePathAry[pagePathAry.length - 1];
```