# How can I get the path of the current folder?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a website that needs to get the folder name and output it to a `var` or `str`.

**Example URL:** `https://myurl.com/my-folder`

**Output:** `my-folder`

**My Code:**

```js
<script>
 var wname = how I get the folders name;
 document.getElementById('workspacename').innerHTML=wname;
</script>
```

```html
<span class/id="workspacename"></span>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i get the name of an html page in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611497/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-an-html-page-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript you can use the location global.
The location global contains quite a bit of information, if you'd like to see whats available you can read the MSDN or open your browsers console and type "location." to see suggestions and console.log them.

```js
var path = location.pathname;
```

You can pair this with substring if you have trailing names in your path.

For example if you wanted 'workspace' from /workspace/some-random-string

You could do

```js
let str = location.pathname.substring(1, location.pathname.length); //removes first /
str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('/'));//substring from 0 to first /
```

Comment: How can I get rid of the slashes?

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to use substring to remove the slashes :)