# Maintaining a persistent active link class after loading the header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap with a menu that I'm trying to set the active class when an item is clicked. I'm able to remove and set the active class with a click event but after the header.php file loads with every new page the active class is removed.  Is there a way to maintain the active class after the header file loads?

header.php

```
<ul class="nav menu">
    <li><a href="test-page1.php">Test Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="test-page2.php">Test Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="test-page3.php">Test Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

footer.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.menu li').click(function(e) {
      $('.menu li.active').removeClass('active');
      var $this = $(this);
      if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
          $this.addClass('active');
      }
    });

});

</script>
```

test-page1.php

```
<?php 
  include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/header.php';
?>

    Some sample test data

<?php
  include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/footer.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most elegant solution, but this is how I've always done it; in the header before you call the navbar you have some sort of page identifier, such as:

```
$pageID = 'home';
```

And then in the HTML, you could have it like this:

```
<a href="home" <?php if($pageID == 'home'){ echo 'class="active"' }; ?>>home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a purely Javascript solution.

```
var loc = location.pathname.substring(1);
$('.menu a[href="' + loc +'"]').parent().addClass('active');
```

This finds your current page name and searches for a link that matches. If you are modifying your url using .htaccess, this may not be possible, or may require some tweaks to get the correct info from your url. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497050/get-the-page-file-name-from-the-address-bar) for additional options for retrieving your page name from your url.