# creating a php website with user-friendly navigation

Tags: php, navigation

We are building a website where user has to login in order to view site's content (similar to what facebook and twitter use)

The problem is that our site's navigation is completely messed up:

- When user opens the site, he is at: **sitename.com**
- When user logs-in, location changes to: **sitename.com/login_success.php**
- when user uses navigation bar, location changes to: **sitename.com/login_success.php#page2** (AJAX is used to change the div content)

In comparison to facebook (url):

- user is loged-in: **sitename.com**
- user is NOT loged-in: **sitename.com**
- user navigates to friend search: **sitename.com/search**
- user navigates to settings: **sitename.com/settings**

Why do sites like facebook have so clean URLs? How do they do it? I'd like to create a clean website, with clean/user-riendly URLs (without `#` or `?` and `&` and `=`) - where do I start? Do we need to use any framework (yii, zend, etc..)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah, you gotta use mod-re-write.

for example, this is how to change `sitename.com/login_success.php#page2` into `sitename.come/page2`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

#first, what is the original request
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /login_success.php#page([0-9]*)
# now use regex to redirect to the clean url structure
RewriteRule ^$ /page%1? [R=301,L,NE]
# now make the clean url serve the content from the ugly one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page([0-9]+) /login_success.php#page$1 [L]
```

I'm not quite sure about that last regex match, but I hope this gets you on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

I believe considerable amount of coding is done in your case.So it would not be advisable to switch to some framework like yii or zend now, this decision should be taken earlier.

Check [how to simplify the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529552/how-to-simplify-the-url).

You can use mod_rewrite of apache web server.

Answer (score 0):

They use `mod_rewrite` and similar tools to clean up their URLs.

`mod_rewrite` is available on Apache. The IIS equivalent is named URL Rewrite.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

You don't need to use a special framework to get this to work, but it helps ease the process, as many frameworks have this feature built-in.

One that comes to mind is Wordpress. Wordpress gives you great control over how this works without having to touch the configuration files too much.